# MS access: how to embed JPEG images and preview them?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

**I use Access 2007**

I have created an OLE field to store JPEG, so I can easily drag them into DATABASE.

That works. Trouble is: **This field does not dispaly the JPEG but the generic JPEG thumb** and I need to double click to open the JPEG and preview it.

Is there a way **to preview JPEG** without having to double click on it ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered storing your images entries for your database as 'text', and simply store the path for the image(//pics/mypic.jpg), rather than the image object itself? If your database is on a shared drive, you can create a folder in the same folder as your database to hold your images. When inserting an image, you can have a textbox and simply type the relative path to that image. This will prevent your database from inflating in size. From there, it is just some simple code to display the picture.

After setting your database up to just store the path names of the images, you can follow these ***easy*** instructions on how to display these images on forms : [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;285820)

I recently switched a couple of my databases from using OLE's to text fields with the path name of the picture and am really satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an Attachment data type to display anything other than bmps. Only bmp images will display in an OLE field (see the Northwind sample database for an example, the Employee form shows bmp images stored in an OLE field).

Alternatively, you can store the path to the image and show it in your form with some VBA. In general, it is best to store paths to images, rather than images, even with databases that have much higher size limits.

Comment: You're answer is correct but I think you're missing a little bit of detail. The user will need to use an Image Frame if he chooses to store images outside of the database and use file links to display them. Also, if the images are quite large, it might be necessary to generate separate thumbnails and show them as image previews for better performance. This will require quite a bit of forethought, code, and testing.

Comment: @HK1 When and if the OP decides to go down the road of getting images from a path, which may be necessary to prevent the database growing exponentially, I will address the issue. At the moment, it is an aside to the OPs problem.

Comment: Problem is : even with BMP, it shows a small THUMB of the BMP, like a 16px16px !

Comment: @user300675 Try [Northwind for Access 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824265). Does the Employee form show pictures?