# Items in details section of continuous (report) view not being uniquely operated on

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report that needs to show multiple pictures. 
In the detail section of my report, I have an unbound imageframe object, and a textbox that contains the absolute path of this image. I have a function that I use elsewhere in my application that displays an image, given a path and an image frame. (continuous view, so multiple strings in the detail section).

In the on current property, as well as on load, (and I added a button to the detail section to test), I execute the code showpic(me.imageframe, me.imagepath).

My problem is that every imageframe in my report gets rendered to the same (first) path. The code isn't executed individually for each element in my report.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Have you got MS Access 2007 or 2010? Because if not, I think you are out of luck.

Comment: I do indeed. The majority of the PC's in the building are now updated to 2007.

Comment: Okay, I think this applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290874/ms-access-how-to-embed-jpeg-images-and-preview-them/11293081#11293081

Comment: Somewhat, I actually have no problem displaying the pictures on single form view forms. The code is executed "on current", and therefore renders the correct picture for each path. The issue is in a continuous view or report view, the same picture gets rendered for each image frame, instead of each picture's path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Access 2010, an image frame, and this code:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    'Image11 is an image frame and MyImage is a path to a bmp
    Me.Image11.Picture = Me.MyImage
End Sub
```

I get a new image for each detail item, but only in print preview. All images were bmp.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that it does work in print preview, but not in report view. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I go slightly mad any time I think about reports, so i try to avoid it. Report events are very touchy indeed and fire in a particular way according to the view.